# Data-Binding in WPF (SCSM Incident Request Form)

Tags: .net, wpf, winforms, xaml, data-binding

I am currently working on an SCSM (Microsoft Service Center Service Manager) 2012 project, in which I have to create a custom incident form for use within the console. I have tried to extend the existing form in the authoring tool, but found it too limited in function. Therefore I went down the  road of working on a completely new form in Visual Studio 2013 (I assume I cannot modify the existing Incident form assembly in VStudio otherwise that would probably make my job alot easier). I have completed the UI of the form, and imported it into the authoring tool to add some functions not present in VStudio (like list picker, etc.). Now I have to go back to the authoring tool (or Visual Studio depending on your answers) and focus on binding the textboxes and controls to actual data… here I kind of am lost. How do I go about doing this? I know I have to point the textbox for example a location on where to pull the data from, but where AM I pulling that data from anyways? For example, the status, the title, etc. These must all be bound to some data object somewhere in the SMDB (Service Manager Database) but that's as far as I know. Any guidance, pointers, tips, even links to documentation I can read would be greatly appreciated! I am a complete newbie at WPF and have been learning as I go, so if possible try to minimize the jargon and explain each step. Thanks in advance!

### **CODE**

Incident_Request_Form.XAML.cs

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
/// using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfControlLibrary1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for UserControl1.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
    {
        public UserControl1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Incident_Request_Form.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfControlLibrary1.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="1000" d:DesignWidth="1024" Background="White">
    <Grid x:Name="Background_Grid" Width="1024" Height="1000" Background="White">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="0*"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Rectangle Fill="#FFF4F4F5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="144" Grid.RowSpan="2" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1024" StrokeThickness="5"/>
        <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="134" Grid.RowSpan="2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="560" Source="logo.png" Margin="10,10,0,0"/>
        <TabControl HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="826" Margin="524,164,0,0" Grid.RowSpan="2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="490">
            <TabItem x:Name="Detail_Tab" Header="Incident Details" Cursor="Hand">
                <Grid Background="#FFE8F4F5" Margin="10,6,0,5.6">
                    <Rectangle x:Name="Assignment_Box_Copy1" Fill="#FF8FCBF7" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="40" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="470" StrokeThickness="0"/>
                    <Label x:Name="Incident_Detail_Label" Content="Incident Detail" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="41" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="355" Cursor="None" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold" FontFamily="Microsoft YaHei UI"/>
                    <Label x:Name="Category_Label" Content="Category:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,40,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                    <Label x:Name="Area_Label" Content="Area:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,66,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                    <Label x:Name="Subarea_Label" Content="Sub-Area:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,92,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                    <Label x:Name="Impact_Label" Content="Impact" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,137,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                    <Label x:Name="Urgency_Label" Content="Urgency" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,163,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                    <Label x:Name="Priority_Label" Content="Priority:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,189,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                    <Label x:Name="Service_Contract_Label" Content="Service Contract:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,235,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                    <Label x:Name="SLA_Target_Date_Label" Content="SLA Target Date:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,266,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                    <Label x:Name="Alert_Status_Label" Content="Alert Status:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,319,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                    <CheckBox x:Name="KB_Candidate_Checkbox" Content="Candiate for Knowledge DB" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,390,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                    <Label x:Name="Hours_Worked_Label" Content="Hours Worked:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,411,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                    <Label x:Name="Closure_Code_Label" Content="Closure Code:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,436,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                    <Label x:Name="Solution_Label" Content="Solution:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,467,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                    <CheckBox x:Name="PM_Candidate_Checkbox" Content="Candidate for Problem Management" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="192,390,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                </Grid>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem x:Name="Activities_Tab" Header="Activities" Cursor="Hand">
                <Grid Background="#FFE8F4F5">
                    <Rectangle x:Name="Assignment_Box_Copy3" Fill="#FF8FCBF7" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="40" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="470" StrokeThickness="0" Margin="10,10,0,0"/>
                    <Label x:Name="Activities_Label_Copy" Content="Activities" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="41" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="355" Cursor="None" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold" FontFamily="Microsoft YaHei UI" Margin="10,10,0,0"/>
                    <TabControl HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="728" Margin="10,56,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="460">
                        <TabItem x:Name="Update_Tab" Header="Update">
                            <Grid x:Name="Update_Tab_Grid" Background="#FFE5E5E5">
                                <Label x:Name="Type_Label" Content="Type:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="24" VerticalAlignment="Top" Cursor="None" FontWeight="Bold" Width="45" FontFamily="Microsoft JhengHei UI" Margin="10,10,0,0"/>
                                <CheckBox x:Name="Visible_2_Customers_Checkbox" Content="Visible To Customer?" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="308,14,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                                <Label x:Name="Update_Label" Content="Update:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,39,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                                <TextBox x:Name="The_Update_TextBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="616" Margin="10,70,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="431"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </TabItem>
                        <TabItem x:Name="Journal_Updates_Tab" Header="Journal Updates">
                            <Grid x:Name="Journal_Updates_Tab_Grid" Background="#FFE5E5E5">
                                <TextBlock x:Name="Journal_Update_Textblock" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="676" Margin="10,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBlock" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="431"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </TabItem>
                        <TabItem x:Name="Historic_Activities_Tab" Header="Historic Activities" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                            <Grid x:Name="Historic_Activities_Tab_Grid" Background="#FFE5E5E5">
                                <Label x:Name="Filter_Label" Content="Filter By Activity Type:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="28"/>
                                <Button x:Name="Filter_Button" Content="Filter" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="29" Margin="10,76,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="125"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </TabItem>
                    </TabControl>
                </Grid>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem x:Name="Related_Tab" Header="Related Records" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Top" Cursor="Hand">
                <Grid x:Name="Tabs" Background="#FFE5E5E5">
                    <TabControl HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="774" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="460">
                        <TabItem x:Name="Interactions_Tab" Header="Interactions">
                            <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5"/>
                        </TabItem>
                        <TabItem x:Name="Incidents_Tab" Header="Incidents">
                            <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5"/>
                        </TabItem>
                        <TabItem x:Name="Changes_Tab" Header="Changes" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                            <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5"/>
                        </TabItem>
                        <TabItem x:Name="Quotes_Tab" Header="Quotes" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="57.6">
                            <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5"/>
                        </TabItem>
                        <TabItem x:Name="Problems_Tab" Header="Problems" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                            <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5"/>
                        </TabItem>
                        <TabItem x:Name="RMA_Tab" Header="RMA" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="57.6">
                            <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5"/>
                        </TabItem>
                    </TabControl>
                </Grid>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem x:Name="History_Tab" Header="History" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="57.6">
                <Grid x:Name="Tab_Grid" Background="#FFE5E5E5" Cursor="Arrow"/>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem x:Name="Attachment_Tab" Header="Attachments" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Top" Cursor="Hand">
                <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5"/>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem x:Name="Alerts_Tab" Header="Alerts" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="57.6">
                <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5"/>
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
        <Rectangle x:Name="Assignment_Box_Copy2" Fill="#FF8FCBF7" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="40" Margin="10,160,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="499" StrokeThickness="0" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
        <Label x:Name="Heading" Content="Incident Information" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="41" Margin="10,164,0,0" Grid.RowSpan="2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="355" Cursor="None" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold" FontFamily="Microsoft YaHei UI"/>
        <Grid x:Name="General_Information_Grid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="785" Margin="10,205,0,0" Grid.RowSpan="2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="509">
            <Label x:Name="Incident_ID" Content="Incident ID:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="24" VerticalAlignment="Top" Cursor="None" FontWeight="Bold" Width="75" FontFamily="Microsoft JhengHei UI"/>
            <Label x:Name="Status_Label" Content="Status:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="24" VerticalAlignment="Top" Cursor="None" FontWeight="Bold" Width="75" FontFamily="Microsoft JhengHei UI" Margin="0,29,0,0"/>
            <Label x:Name="Status_Reasoning_Label" Content="Status Reasoning:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Cursor="None" FontWeight="Bold" FontFamily="Microsoft JhengHei UI" Margin="0,53,0,0"/>
            <Rectangle x:Name="Assignment_Box" Fill="#FF8FCBF7" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="40" Margin="0,84,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="499" StrokeThickness="0"/>
            <Label x:Name="Assignment_Label" Content="Assignment" Margin="0,84,223,0" Height="38" Width="137" FontSize="22" FontWeight="Bold" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
            <Label x:Name="Assignment_Group_Label" Content="Assignment Group:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Cursor="None" FontWeight="Bold" FontFamily="Microsoft JhengHei UI" Margin="0,124,0,0"/>

            <Label x:Name="Assignee_Label" Content="Assignee:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Cursor="None" FontWeight="Bold" FontFamily="Microsoft JhengHei UI" Margin="0,150,0,0"/>
            <Label x:Name="Vendor_Label" Content="Vendor:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Cursor="None" FontWeight="Bold" FontFamily="Microsoft JhengHei UI" Margin="0,176,0,0"/>
            <Label x:Name="Reference_Number_Label" Content="Vendor Reference Number:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Cursor="None" FontWeight="Bold" FontFamily="Microsoft JhengHei UI" Margin="0,202,0,0"/>
            <Rectangle x:Name="Assignment_Box_Copy" Fill="#FF8FCBF7" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="35" Margin="0,233,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="499" StrokeThickness="0"/>
            <Label x:Name="Afected_Items" Content="Affected Items" Margin="0,230,0,0" Height="38" FontSize="22" FontWeight="Bold" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="165"/>
            <Label x:Name="Status_Label_Copy" Content="Status:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="24" VerticalAlignment="Top" Cursor="None" FontWeight="Bold" Width="75" FontFamily="Microsoft JhengHei UI" Margin="0,29,0,0"/>
            <Label x:Name="Service_Label" Content="Service:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Cursor="None" FontWeight="Bold" FontFamily="Microsoft JhengHei UI" Margin="0,277,0,0"/>
            <Label x:Name="Affected_CI_Label" Content="Affected CI:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Cursor="None" FontWeight="Bold" FontFamily="Microsoft JhengHei UI" Margin="0,308,0,0"/>
            <CheckBox x:Name="Critical_CI_Checkbox" Content="Critical CI" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="2,346,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            <CheckBox x:Name="Pending_Change_Checkbox" Content="Pending Change" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="156,346,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            <CheckBox x:Name="CI_Operational_Checkbox" Content="CI is Operational (No Outage)" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="326,346,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            <Label x:Name="Outage_Start_Label" Content="Outage Start:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Cursor="None" FontWeight="Bold" FontFamily="Microsoft JhengHei UI" Margin="0,367,0,0"/>
            <Label x:Name="Outage_End_Label" Content="Outage End:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Cursor="None" FontWeight="Bold" FontFamily="Microsoft JhengHei UI" Margin="0,393,0,0"/>
            <Label x:Name="Location_Label" Content="Location:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Cursor="None" FontWeight="Bold" FontFamily="Microsoft JhengHei UI" Margin="0,424,0,0"/>
            <Label x:Name="Title_Label" Content="Title:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Cursor="None" FontWeight="Bold" FontFamily="Microsoft JhengHei UI" Margin="0,455,0,0"/>
            <Label x:Name="Description_Label" Content="Description:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Cursor="None" FontWeight="Bold" FontFamily="Microsoft JhengHei UI" Margin="0,521,0,0"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="Vendor_Reference_Textbox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="26" Margin="199,202,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="300" ToolTip="Enter Vendor Reference # Here"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="Title_Textbox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="26" Margin="10,486,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="489" ToolTip="Enter Vendor Reference # Here"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="Description_Textbox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="228" Margin="10,547,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="489" ToolTip="Enter Vendor Reference # Here"/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Wall of text and no code. I won't read all that. Close-voting.

Comment: Not very user-friendly... This was my first post and I thought I was required to be detailed so I gave as much detail as possible. Sorry if this was too much text to read. Will provide code now - was looking for pointers as where to go didnt think you needed my code

Comment: you're expected to provide details about **what you tried** and how it doesn't work, and your question is tagged bot `winforms` and `wpf` and you talk about something called SCSM that I have no idea about. Your question is completely unclear, despite the amount of text on it. Please remove all irrelevant stuff (salutations and other useless stuff, StackOverflow is NOT a forum). and post a proper, specific question including relevant code.

Comment: SCSM uses WPF as its framework... my question had to do with WPF really. And I will try to edit my question to remove my polite statements and be more specific I guess.

Comment: What (if anything) is the `DataContext` of this Window? how/where do you open this window from? I'm sorry I'm no familiar with SCSM. Also, you shouldn't be using the Visual Studio designer in WPF.

Comment: What exactly is datacontext, the data source? This window is my custom implementation of an incident request form from Microsoft System Center Service Manager 2012. However, I have now discovered I created a new class and was struggling with where I should bind the data, but What I should have done was extend the existing incident class to add the properties I wanted. I am one step closer and will post the solution when I get there.

Answer (score 0):

You bind it like this:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Title, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  Background="#FFECC3C3" Margin="5,0,10,0"/>

 <scwpf:SingleInstancePicker Instance="{Binding Path=Microsoft.SystemCenter.ConfigurationManager.MobileDevice, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" BaseClassId="c928e643-baa3-2cd7-3662-739befc4ac43" Margin="5,0,10,0"/>
```

Check this videotutorial also:

http://www.concurrency.com/blog/building-custom-forms-for-service-manager-with-visual-studio/

Cheers
Morten

Comment: Thank you very much Morten! I actually ended up figuring this out on my own, I have a meeting soon, but when I am done I will come back and post my solution so others can learn as well.